# How do I know that a COM Object is compatible with different COM UUIDS?

Tags: c++, com, direct3d, direct2d

Based on the MSDN for Direct 3D 11 Graphics the documentation section "How to create an immediate context" shows the following code:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
// Get a pointer to the back buffer
hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ),
( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
```

The here called `pBackBuffer` is of Type `ID3D11Texture2D`.
The documentation for the GetBuffer method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-getbuffer)
describes the second Parameter as Type **`REFIID (The type of interface used to manipulate the buffer)` and the third as `void** A pointer to a back-buffer interface.`**

Now a different section in the documentation about Direct2d shows the following snippet to write Direct2d content to a Direct3d buffer:

```
 hr = m_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(
        0,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBackBuffer)
        );
```

Here the BackBuffer is used in `CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget` as first parameter which is a `IDXGISurface` which means the Backbuffer that I got is an IDXGISurface.

How do I know that I can pass in `ID3D11Texture2D` and `IDXGISurface` to that GetBuffer method when the MSDN only describes the parameter as REFIID (see above) ? And how can I figure out what elese I can pass in there?

Comment: If it's not documented, you don't know. There are discovery mechanisms in COM but they are rarely implemented. One thing you know is, in general, you can get the different version of an interface from one of the version. ie: you can get IBlah from IBlah2 (and the reverse if the system supports it). But from a Texture to a Surface, it has to be documented. The last resort is to disassemble the .dll with a tool such as IDA and it will tell you what are the implemented interfaces if the PDBs are available ...

Comment: Note that [`IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBackBuffer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) is just a preprocessor macro wrapper that resolves to `__uuidof(*pBackBuffer), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer`. See [COM Coding Practices: The IID_PPV_ARGS Macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/com-coding-practices#the-iid_ppv_args-macro)

Comment: The REFIID is crucial, it describes the type of interface pointer reference you pass as the 3rd argument.  So crucial that they came up with the IID_PPV_ARGS macro to auto-generate the 2nd and 3rd arguments.  In other words, there is no distinction between the two snippets, just written differently.  You'll know it can't supply the interface from the hr return value.

Comment: All three comments above are great. To add a bit, if you absolutely need to know what else can be requested, you'd step into the call with debugger in disassembly mode and check that `IID` argument is being compared to. This is a sort of last resort, but sometimes if what's indeed being done.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I will take a look at it with a debugger and see what comes up. But so far I guess I need to rely on the documentation and what is there

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Read the Microsoft Docs article [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).**

The DirectX APIs use a "lite" form of COM, so they don't fully implement all the possible features the Component Object Model (COM):

- They use reference counting for lifetime using `IUnknown` but this a modified form where `IDeviceChild` objects will all be immediately invalid when their parent `IDevice` interface is fully released. You can use `AddRef` and `Release`, although for C++ you are better off using something like [ComPtr](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).
- DirectX APIs don't support "single-threaded apartment"
- Some DirectX APIs do not support `CoCreateInstance` and have to be created via a specific factory API.
- They do not implement aggregation.
- DirectX APIs don't generally implement out-of-process/remote process behavior

To your question, DirectX APIs generally support a limited number of interfaces and you use `QueryInterface` to 'down-cast' them. A given DirectX object will support `IUnknown`, and the IID for each class in the hierarchy on that system (i.e. if it's `ID3D11Device2` then it will support `ID3D11Device1` and `ID3D11Device`). With C++, you typically just use inheritance to go up the hierarchy but you can use `QueryInterface`.

Otherwise, there are only going to be a few specific cases of objects supporting multiple interfaces, such as DXGI interop with Direct3D for [swapchains](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) or [device-shared textures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis). In other words, most cases result in `E_NOINTERACE`.

See also [The Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) and [Reference Counting (Direct3D 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-api-features-reference-counting),